# make first section of the page stick at the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At my Page there are tow sections, a header div and the contents div. I want JS or jquery solution to stick the header section at the top, so that when user scrolls the contents section would cross and cover the header section.

html:

```
<div id="header">
    <h3>I'd like to stick here at the background, please! </h3>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <h3>I'd like to cross over the header when user scrolls.</h3>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KNh46/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: misunderstood, so you want the content to scroll **over** the header, not *under*. Then it should be like:

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}

#content {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 100px;
    z-index: 101;
}
```

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/aorcsik/v7zav/

---

If your header is fixed height, say `100px`, then:

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0;
}

#content {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

This way when scrolled to the top, the header won't overlay the content, but when you start to scroll down, it will.

Comment: Will `margin-top` work?...I think 'padding-top` might work better.

Comment: Works for me, check the fiddles, for the scroll over version: http://jsfiddle.net/aorcsik/v7zav/ and the scroll under version: http://jsfiddle.net/aorcsik/v7zav/1/

Answer (score 1):

you should add css:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0}
#header{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background:#ccc;
}
h3{
    text-align:center;
}

#content{
    background:#f1f1f1;
    padding-top:200px;
    min-height:500px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KNh46/1/)

Comment: I am aware of fixed positions, Did you see the jsfiddle? I want exact layout at the page load, but when the user starts to scroll, the header is fixed there and the contents div startrs to cover the header.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, if I understand your question:

```
<div id="content_wrapper" style="position:relative">
    <div id="header" style="z-index:1; position:absolute; top:0px">
        <h3>I'd like to stick here at the background, please! </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="z-index:5">
        <h3>I'd like to cross over the header when user scrolls.</h3>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed on my projects with no problems. ScrollToFixed allows you to set when the div will be fixed based on the scroll position.

fiddle with example: jsfiddle.net/ZczEt/167/

Answer (score 0):

I myself came with another solution :

add another container div to the header and then position that div to fixed, and make the contents to be absolute. but this way you need to specify a min-height or height for the header:

http://jsfiddle.net/pna54/

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="container">
        <h3>I'd like to stick here at the background, please! </h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <h3>I'd like to cross over the header when user scrolls.</h3>
</div>
```

css:

```
div{margin:0;padding:0}

    h3{
        padding:0;margin:0;
        padding-top: 100px;
        padding-bottom:100px;
        text-align:center;
    }

    #header{
        background:#ccc;
        min-height:200px;
        width:500px;
        position:relative;
    }
    .container{
        position:fixed;
        width:100%;
        max-width:500px;
    }
    #content{

        background:#f1f1f1;
        min-height: 500px;
        position: absolute;
        width:500px;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pna54/